# Windows 10 shut down without provoking it

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

I was typing a post on reddit while suddenly (without any windows update pending and without me shutting it down) my pc shut down normally (not power off I got the blue screen with the "shutting down" message and the loading circle)

It did not restart, it just shut down and during the shut down screen there was no % sign of installing or downloading any updates.

It also wasn't sudden (it took like 10 seconds or so to shut down)

How could this happen? Could somebody else do that to my computer? (I mean how realistic is this scenario? )

I use windows 10 64 bit and bitdefender total security.

Comment: You didn’t provide any information about make and model of your computer. This is a common thing that happens on an overheating computer, especially laptops.

Comment: Set your activity period and/or set the scheduled installation time of the update or pause updates or defer updates or use WSUS

Comment: @Appleoddity I use a desktop computer and it so happens to be open lid as well, are you sure that shutting down because of overheating happens with a normal shut down procedure and not like an abrupt power off of the system (instant and sudden black screen) ?

Comment: @Ramhound I am 100% sure there has been no updating/downloading for updates going on my PC also no new software has been installed

Comment: I’m not sure if your problem is heat. But I am sure that some systems shut down normally due to heat and do not shut off abruptly. Specifically, this happens if you have the Intel Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework. However, because your system shuts down normally, you should start in your SYSTEM event log which will detail what application shutdown the system and why. At least you’ll figure out better where to look.

Comment: Have you checked the event viewer logs for clue as to the reason around the time the reboot occurred? You may want to start there just in case there is something there that indicates what the reason may be. If you happen to find something in the event viewer that related to the reboot whether unexpected or whatever you see, please [edit] your question and add this detail.